# Unable to minimize negative numbers in clingo

Tags: optimization, clingo

I ran into an issue trying to optimize a value that can run into negative numbers:

```
{ choose(-1..10)} = 1.

#minimize {C@1 : choose(C)}.
```

With the above code, after I run it, I obtain:

```
Answer: 1
choose(-1)
Optimization: 0
OPTIMUM FOUND

Models       : 1
  Optimum    : yes
Optimization : 0
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.004s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.000s
```

Shouldn't the minimum value be -1? Or is there more to do to minimize a negative cost?